# Why does Elasticsearch word_delimiter_graph work differently than expected?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, full-text-search

The "cool thing about `word_delimiter_graph`" is that it indexes positionLength if it is anything other than 1.

I indexed `FooBar Baz` using `word_delimiter_graph` with `"generate_word_parts": "true", "preserve_original": "true", "split_on_case_change": "true"` which tokenizes as follows:

```
pos 0 foobar  (positionLength 2)
pos 0 foo 
pos 1 bar
pos 2 baz
```

If I do a phrase search for `"foobar baz"`, my search analyzer (standard analyzer) uses these tokens:

```
pos 0 foobar
pos 1 baz
```

If the positionLength is meaningful at all, then I would think that this search should match the indexed text, but it does not.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This lucene issue is related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4312 It seems to indicate that the `positionLength` is not indexed. Therefore the index is identical for `word_delimiter` and `word_delimiter_graph`.

Answer (score 2):

`word_delimiter_graph` is not completely implemented and is not useful for "better" match_phrase searches as the Elasticsearch documentation would seem to indicate.

Based upon this ongoing discussion issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4312 the `positionLength` isn't indexed, so `word_delimiter_graph` tokens are stored on disk no differently than `word_delimiter` tokens. Even if this information was indexed, we would not be able to make use of it until corresponding search code was built.

#### related

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7398
- https://2019.berlinbuzzwords.de/19/session/complete-precise-graph-based-phrase-query-spannearquery.html